# Update UI in component when observable emits

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, gatsby

On a Gatsby site I have a navbar that should show some options depending on the logged in state of the user. The logged in state is handled by an observable. I am subscribing to the observable on the page object and passing the user object to the component in the props, but the UI does not update when the user object changes. How can I trigger the UI to update when the `user$` observable emits a new value.

On the page component, I'm subscribing to the observable and using that to set a variable that can be passed to the Navbar component.

```
const ExamplePage = () => {
  let user = {}

  user$.subscribe(
    (authUser) => {
      user = authUser
    }
  )

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Navbar user={user}></Navbar>
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

In the Navbar component I am using props to check the user and conditionally render the links.

```
const navbar = (props) => {
  const getAuthControls = () => {
    if (props.user && props.user.email) {
      return <>
        <li>
          <Link to="/account">Account</Link>
        </li>
      </>
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  return <nav className={classNames.join(' ')}>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      {getAuthControls()}
    </ul>
  </nav>
}
```

What's the best way to trigger a UI update in the embedded component?

Comment: when subscribing to an observable you should use a `useEffect` and return a function to clean up the subscription. when the observable returns a value instead of `user = authUser` make use of `useState` and set the state to `authUser`. [Hooks Api](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

Comment: @JacobSmit Thanks that helps. Calling `setState` in the `useEffect` seems to cause `useEffect` to be called again which gets it into an infinite loop of `useEffect`. How can I stop that?

Comment: I've fixed it with the solution detailed here: https://medium.com/@andrewmyint/infinite-loop-inside-useeffect-react-hooks-6748de62871

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution, sorry I didn't notice your reply a bit sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-hydrate your component with the changes of the user login/logout so, you need to use a `useState` instead of a `let` variable. Something like this should work:

```
const ExamplePage = () => {
  const {user, setUser}=useState('')

  user$.subscribe(
    (authUser) => {
      setUser(authUser)
    }
  )

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Navbar user={user}></Navbar>
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

You can also use a `useEffect` like:

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    setUser(authUser)
  },[user])
```

To avoid an infinite looping in your observer or to have a custom hook to retrieve the current status of the user.